# How to get difference based on conditions in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below-mentioned df in r:

df<-

```
ID    Date                 Instance    Price    Volume     Grade
K-1   2021-07-01 04:01:20     1        1000     2          5000
K-1   2021-07-02 22:01:29     2        1000     1.4        4500
K-1   2021-07-04 13:05:04     3        800      1.4        4500
K-2   2021-07-01 09:11:26     1        7000     1.5        3500
K-2   2021-07-01 14:01:40     2        2500     1.5        3000
K-3   2021-07-05 12:23:24     1        1000     2.1        2000
K-4   2021-07-06 14:11:40     1        15000    2.5        1500
K-4   2021-07-08 14:19:25     2        18000    2.7        2500
```

By using the above dataframe, I need to derive the following details based on the certain condition.

Where, I need to identify whether the change in `Price`, `Volume` and `Grade` are on higher side or lower side based on the `Instance` column. `Instance` is nothing but modification raw of a particular unique `ID`.

- `Diff_DateTime` is difference of Date between last instance for an unique `ID` minus first instance of that `ID`. If it is less than 24 hours then generate a value in hours or in Days.
- `Rng_Price` is range of difference in bucket `0-500`, `500-1500`, `1500-3000` and `3000+`
- `Rng_Vol` is range of difference in bucket `0-0.5`, `0.5-1`, `1-2` and `2+`
- `Rng_Grd` is range of difference in bucket `0-5001,` 500-1000`,` 1000-2000`and`2000+`

Initial and Final are first and last Price, Volume and Grade value based on the instance.

Required Df<-

```
ID   Count_Instance    Chng_Pri    Chng_Vol  Chng_Grd     Diff_DateTime  Rng_Pric   Rng_Vol    Rng_Grd      Initial_Pri     Final_Pri      Initial_Vol   Final_Vol      Initial_Grd   Final_Grd
    
K-1    3             Low         Low       Low          3.5 Days       0-500      0.5-1.0     0-500        1000            800            2             1.4            5000          4500
K-2    2             Low         Constant  Low          5h             3000+      0        0-500        7000            2500           1.5           1.5            3500          3000
K-3    1             No Inst     No Inst   No Inst      No Inst        No Inst    No Inst     No Inst      No Inst       No Inst        No Inst       No Inst        No Inst       No Inst 
K-4    2             High        High      High         2 Days         1500-3000  0-0.5      500-1000     15000           18000          2.5           2.7            1500          2500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Instance) %>% 
  summarise(
    Count_Instance = n(),
    Diff_Date = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, 
                        difftime(last(Date), first(Date), units=c("hours")),
                        NA_real_),
    Rng_Price = case_when(
      Count_Instance == 1                     ~ NA_character_,
      abs(last(Price) - first(Price)) <= 500  ~ "0-500",
      abs(last(Price) - first(Price)) <= 1500 ~ "500 - 1500",
      abs(last(Price) - first(Price)) <= 3000 ~ "1500 - 3000",
      TRUE                                    ~ "3000+"
      ),
    Rng_Vol = case_when(
      Count_Instance == 1                      ~ NA_character_,
      abs(last(Volume) - first(Volume)) == 0   ~ "0",
      abs(last(Volume) - first(Volume)) <= 0.5 ~ "0 - 0.5",
      abs(last(Volume) - first(Volume)) <= 1   ~ "0.5 - 1",
      abs(last(Volume) - first(Volume)) <= 2   ~ "1 - 2",
      TRUE                                     ~ "2+"
      ),
    Rng_Grd = case_when(
      Count_Instance == 1                     ~ NA_character_,
      abs(last(Grade) - first(Grade)) == 0    ~ "0",
      abs(last(Grade) - first(Grade)) <= 500  ~ "0 - 500",
      abs(last(Grade) - first(Grade)) <= 1000 ~ "500 - 1000",
      abs(last(Grade) - first(Grade)) <= 2000 ~ "1000 - 2000",
      TRUE                                    ~ "2000+"
      ),
    Initital_Pri = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, first(Price), NA_real_),
    Final_Pri    = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, last(Price), NA_real_),
    Initial_Vol  = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, first(Volume), NA_real_),
    Final_Vol    = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, last(Volume), NA_real_),
    Initial_Grd  = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, first(Grade), NA_real_),
    Final_Grd    = if_else(Count_Instance != 1, last(Grade), NA_real_)
    )
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  ID    Count_Instance Diff_Date       Rng_Price   Rng_Vol Rng_Grd   Initital_Pri Final_Pri Initial_Vol Final_Vol
  <chr>          <int> <drtn>          <chr>       <chr>   <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 K-1                3 81.062222 hours 0-500       0.5 - 1 0 - 500           1000       800         2         1.4
2 K-2                2  4.837222 hours 3000+       0       0 - 500           7000      2500         1.5       1.5
3 K-3                1        NA hours NA          NA      NA                  NA        NA        NA        NA  
4 K-4                2 48.129167 hours 1500 - 3000 0 - 0.5 500 - 10~        15000     18000         2.5       2.7
# ... with 2 more variables: Initial_Grd <dbl>, Final_Grd <dbl>
```

Three things are missing:

- You need some function to convert the `Diff_Date` into your desired format.
- The `Chng_`-columns are missing since there was no algorithm for creating those values provided.
- Instead of "No Inst" for an instance count of 1, I used different `NA`'s. You can't put `No Inst` into a column with real numbers unless you want to convert those numbers into a character/string.

### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c("K-1", "K-1", "K-1", "K-2", "K-2", "K-3", 
"K-4", "K-4"), Date = structure(c(1625104880, 1625256089, 1625396704, 
1625123486, 1625140900, 1625480604, 1625573500, 1625746765), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Instance = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
    Price = c(1000, 1000, 800, 7000, 2500, 1000, 15000, 18000
    ), Volume = c(2, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 2.1, 2.5, 2.7), Grade = c(5000, 
    4500, 4500, 3500, 3000, 2000, 1500, 2500)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```